# How to make a button that functions as a link in eclipse for android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I need to know how I could make a button that opens the androids web browser and navigates to a specific URL. I'm using eclipse and already know how to make buttons and click listeners. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code to onClick():

```
        // Launch a browser
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.yahoo.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.android.com");
websiteIntent.setData(uri);
startActivity(websiteIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
startActivity(intent);
```